# Why does Ubuntu 16.04 remove 'MountFlags=slave' from systemd-udevd.service?

Tags: 16.04, systemd

Why does Ubuntu 16.04 delete `MountFlags=slave` from `systemd-udevd.service` which is different from systemd upstream?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is given in [the patch removing this option](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/tree/debian/patches/udev-re-enable-mount-propagation-for-udevd.patch?h=ubuntu/xenial):

> laptop-mode-tools remounts file systems from within a udev rule to
>   apply certain mount options. With MountFlags=slave, those mounts then
>   become private to the systemd-udevd namespace and are no longer
>   accessible from outside the namespace. While the root cause is the
>   broken behaviour of laptop-mode-tools, with mount propagation turned
>   off, this can result in a read-only root file system. Therefore revert
>   the relevant parts from commit
>   c2c13f2df42e0691aecabe3979ea81cd7faa35c7 to re-enable mount
>   propagation for udevd.

Comment: As @muru found, when you want to answer "why did this change?", great sources include project change logs and git commit histories. Since it was a distro-specific change, he checked out the "./patches" directory of the related package shipped by the OS, and found the answer there.